# Decrypt data using RijndaelManaged in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

In my asp.net project i have encrypted data using RijndaelManaged (from C#) and save the data in SQL database. I want to decrypt these data by SQL query and return. See below,

```
SELECT Name FROM Person
```

Here "Name" is encrypted from C# code. I want to decrypt it from SQL Query not from c#. How can I do it?

Comment: I think that you will probably need a CLR stored procedure to accomplish the exact decryption needed to restore your data to plaintext since you have not used one of the algorithms inherent in SQL Server.

Comment: @Greenspark.  Yes. I have created a CLR Stored Procedure for this and i was able to accomplish my requirement. Thank you